# Why is this CSS transition only working correctly on the some clicks? How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I try to create a chain of CSS transitions with jQuery. The 1st transition is triggered by a click event and the 2nd is triggered by transition end event.

The expected process is like this:
click --> scale up --> wait 1s --> rotate in y axis & shrink
requirement: the latest clicked element must be in front of the others during transition

I model the problem like this:
Class"enlarge" for scaling up and class"spinY" for rotation.
click event --> add class"enlarge"
transition end event --> Remove class"enlarge" & class"spinY" if having class"spinY" else add class"spinY"

```js
$(function() {
  var zValue = 0;

  // event listener detect click
  $(".main ").on("click", "div.flat", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("spinY", "enlarge")) {
      // increment z variable & set z-index to it
      $(this).css("z-index", ++zValue);
      // add class for css transition, enlarge
      $(this).addClass("enlarge");
    }
  });

  // event listener detect end of transition
  $(".main ").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", "div.flat", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("spinY")) {
      $(this).removeClass("enlarge spinY");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("spinY");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.flat, .labeling {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 height: 3em;
 width: 3em;
}

.flat, .flat .rect {
 border: 1px solid silver;
}

.rect {
 position: relative;
 left: 0.2em;
 top: 0.15em;
 height: 70%;
 width: 80%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 200%;
}

.available .rect{
 color: white;
 background: #FFAA00;
}

.flat.enlarge {
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
 transform: rotateY(0turn) scale(3.2);
}

.flat.spinY {
 -webkit-transition: all 1 linear 1s;
 transition: all 1 linear 1s;
 transform: rotateY(5turn);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xqvd7ng/1/ 
Feel free to try the code.

I expect each click triggering the same process aforementioned. However, I find **except the 1st click, other's rotation transition is skipped**. Please **explain the cause of this and provide the solution**. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to increase `z-index` in the JS code, simply make the `z-index` of the transformed element higher in the CSS

```js
$(function() {
  var zValue = 0;

  // event listener detect click
  $(".main ").on("click", "div.flat", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("spinY", "enlarge")) {
      // add class for css transition, enlarge
      $(this).addClass("enlarge");
    }
  });

  // event listener detect end of transition
  $(".main ").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", "div.flat", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("spinY")) {
      $(this).removeClass("enlarge spinY");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("spinY");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.flat,
.labeling {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
}

.flat,
.flat .rect {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.rect {
  position: relative;
  left: 0.2em;
  top: 0.15em;
  height: 70%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200%;
}

.available .rect {
  color: white;
  background: #FFAA00;
}

.flat.enlarge {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: rotateY(0turn) scale(3.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.flat.spinY {
  transition: all 1 linear 1s;
  transform: rotateY(5turn);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or if you want to keep the `z-index` in the JS code, make the transition more specific so it target only the transform and you will avoid triggering `transitionend` when changing the `z-index`:

```js
$(function() {
  var zValue = 0;

  // event listener detect click
  $(".main ").on("click", "div.flat", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("spinY", "enlarge")) {
    
     $(this).css("z-index", ++zValue);
      // add class for css transition, enlarge
      $(this).addClass("enlarge");
    }
  });

  // event listener detect end of transition
  $(".main ").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", "div.flat", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("spinY")) {
      $(this).removeClass("enlarge spinY");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("spinY");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.flat,
.labeling {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
}

.flat,
.flat .rect {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.rect {
  position: relative;
  left: 0.2em;
  top: 0.15em;
  height: 70%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200%;
}

.available .rect {
  color: white;
  background: #FFAA00;
}

.flat.enlarge {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  transform: rotateY(0turn) scale(3.2);
}

.flat.spinY {
  transition: transform 1 linear 1s;
  transform: rotateY(5turn);
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

The main issue with your code is that you are doing a transition of 2 properties (z-index and transform) so you trigger `transitionend` two times. To better illustrate the issue add `console.log()` and you will notice that you are adding/removing the spin class rapidly:

```js
$(function(){ 
 var zValue = 0;
 
 // event listener detect click
 $(".main ").on("click", "div.flat", function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass("spinY", "enlarge")) {
   // increment z variable & set z-index to it
      $(this).css("z-index", ++zValue);
   // add class for css transition, enlarge
   $(this).addClass("enlarge");
  }
 });

 // event listener detect end of transition
 $(".main ").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", "div.flat", function(){
    console.log('end!');
  if($(this).hasClass("spinY")) {
   $(this).removeClass("enlarge spinY");
      console.log('Remove class');
  } else {
   $(this).addClass("spinY");
      console.log('add class');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.flat, .labeling {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 height: 3em;
 width: 3em;
}

.flat, .flat .rect {
 border: 1px solid silver;
}

.rect {
 position: relative;
 left: 0.2em;
 top: 0.15em;
 height: 70%;
 width: 80%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 200%;
}

.available .rect{
 color: white;
 background: #FFAA00;
}

.flat.enlarge {
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
 transform: rotateY(0turn) scale(3.2);
}

.flat.spinY {
 -webkit-transition: all 1 linear 1s;
 transition: all 1 linear 1s;
 transform: rotateY(5turn);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="main">
   <div class="flat available">
    <div class="rect"></div>
   </div>
       <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
     </div>
          <div class="flat available">
            <div class="rect"></div>
          </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't happen the first time because initially there is no value set for `z-index` so you will have no transition.

Set a default value and even the first you will get nothing:

```js
$(function(){ 
 var zValue = 0;
 
 // event listener detect click
 $(".main ").on("click", "div.flat", function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass("spinY", "enlarge")) {
   // increment z variable & set z-index to it
      $(this).css("z-index", ++zValue);
   // add class for css transition, enlarge
   $(this).addClass("enlarge");
  }
 });

 // event listener detect end of transition
 $(".main ").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", "div.flat", function(){
    console.log('end!');
  if($(this).hasClass("spinY")) {
   $(this).removeClass("enlarge spinY");
      console.log('Remove class');
  } else {
   $(this).addClass("spinY");
      console.log('add class');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.flat, .labeling {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 height: 3em;
 width: 3em;
}

.flat, .flat .rect {
 border: 1px solid silver;
  z-index:0;
}

.rect {
 position: relative;
 left: 0.2em;
 top: 0.15em;
 height: 70%;
 width: 80%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 200%;
}

.available .rect{
 color: white;
 background: #FFAA00;
}

.flat.enlarge {
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 transition: all 1s ease;
 transform: rotateY(0turn) scale(3.2);
}

.flat.spinY {
 -webkit-transition: all 1 linear 1s;
 transition: all 1 linear 1s;
 transform: rotateY(5turn);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="main">
   <div class="flat available">
    <div class="rect"></div>
   </div>
       <div class="flat available">
      <div class="rect"></div>
     </div>
          <div class="flat available">
            <div class="rect"></div>
          </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The solution is to either avoid changing z-index (or any other property) OR adjust the transition to only work with transform.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had no idea that the transition end event is triggered once for each property. I would only attach transform to transition.
I would keep the increment of z-index because user can click other buttons while the transition is not completed yet. **The latest clicked button must be at the front.**

Answer (score 0):

in theory, what you are doing should do the job, the problem is that the z-index is applied when the transition is already in process, this is just a sync problem.

```
    $(function(){   
    var zValue = 0;

    // event listener detect click
    $(".main ").on("click", "div.flat", function(){

        if (!$(this).hasClass("spinY", "enlarge")) {

        /*
     set z-index that will suffice since the other elements do not
     have one defined      
      */
          $(this).css("z-index",1);

            // add class for css transition, enlarge
            $(this).addClass("enlarge");
        }
    });

    // event listener detect end of transition
    $(".main ").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", "div.flat", function(){

        if($(this).hasClass("spinY")) {
            $(this).removeClass("enlarge spinY");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("spinY");
        }
         /*
         delete the property and so clicked will always have a 
         greater position
         */ 
         $(this).css("z-index","");
    });
});
```

im forked your example so you can see it work

> https://jsfiddle.net/michelnovellino/jxag7859/6/

Comment: You point out the cause but the details and solution are not ok. Why $(this).css("z-index", ++zValue) cause the problem? On the other hand, I have to increment the zValue and set div's z-index to it because it always be in front of the others.

Comment: Sorry, but your fiddle is not working. In your work only 1st click triggers the transition. Moreover, you may observe that the enlarged button on the left is always behind the enlarged button on the right.

Comment: try now, I forgot to save the changes at the end, I'm sorry